# stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString Regular Expression

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I'm developing a Mac app and I'm trying to replace use NSString's stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString. I'm doing something like:

```
NSString *new = [s stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"(special-tag)*.*</body" withString:html];
```

On an NSString. But whenever I try to use this function with a regular expression it seems to break. Is there something I'm missing? I found a few external regex libraries, but I'd rather use something built in that has similar functionality.

Any advice? Thanks in advance! EDIT - I know why it's breaking, I need help figuring out how to do an NSString replace with regular expressions

Comment: it will replace the `(special-tag)*.*</body` string rather than `(special-tag)*.*</body` reg ex

Comment: Right I'm just wondering how to do an NSString replace with regular expressions

Answer (score 2):

As the name suggest `stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString` `OccurrencesOfString` it's a string not a RegEx. So it will replace your string rather than your RegEx.

-----------Edited-----------------
I haven't used regex before hope this will give you the idea

```
NSString *string = @"this is your string";
NSError *error = NULL;
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"\\b(a|b)(c|d)\\b" options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:&error];
NSString *modifiedString = [regex stringByReplacingMatchesInString:string options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [string length]) withTemplate:@"$2$1"];
```

Here is the [NSRegularExpression Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSRegularExpression_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009708)

Comment: Thanks! I'm more wondering how to do it with a regular expression if that's possible

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the `NSRegularExpression` class. It sounds like the [`-stringByReplacingMatchesInString:options:range:withTemplate:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSRegularExpression_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSRegularExpression/stringByReplacingMatchesInString%3aoptions%3arange%3awithTemplate%3a) method will fit your needs. You might also like [`–replaceMatchesInString:options:range:withTemplate:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSRegularExpression_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSRegularExpression/replaceMatchesInString%3aoptions%3arange%3awithTemplate%3a).